# Cover page lay-out

Tags: titles, front-matter, covers

I'd like to make the cover page as seen in the image below and be able to put it in a .tex-file.
This cover page itself is made within LaTeX, but it's not compatible with XeTeX, and it uses at least 3 different files with definitions etc.

I'd thus like to know if it's possible to make a fresh, new .tex-file, perhaps named "Titlepage", making me able to just put in the main .tex-file `\include{cover}` without all the other unnecessary fuss.

Could someone help me on this rather 'big' question?
I haven't got any clue on how to do this. Suppose that the banner image is called image.jpg.

Thank you very much indeed in advance.

[image]

Comment: For a start: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: btw, there is a difference between a *cover* and a *titlepage*.

Comment: Let's call it a cover, then. I'll look into your link asap.

Comment: If you provided the current solution, people could help you clean it up and make it work with XeTeX. Especially if you gave us the dimensions of the image. Why should we start from scratch when you are sitting on a working solution, albeit one which needs a bit of tidying up? We don't even know what paper size you are using or what fonts that uses or any of the information which the current code could easily provide. Failing that, create the cover separately and then use `pdfpages` and `\includepdf{cover}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,x11names]{report}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{blueXIIdark}{cmyk}{1,.8,.30,.05}
\definecolor{blueXIIlight}{cmyk}{.0,.30,1,.00}

%\vspace{5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([yshift=-1.8in]current page.north) node[inner sep=0] (a) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kleurlabel}};
\node[anchor=east,xshift=-8mm] (example-tabular) at (a.east)   {
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Faculteit Geneeskunde en \\
\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Gezondheidswetenschappen \\
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{8cm}

\Huge\color{blueXIIdark} Here comes the title of the dissertation

\vspace{8.5cm}

\large\color{black}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
& \textbf{\Large Author Name}\vspace{0.8cm}\\
  Promotor: & Profefschrift ingediend ter verkrijgen \\
Prof. dr. ir. B. Leader & van de graad van Master of Science\\
& in de geneeskunde\\[2cm]
& Academiejaar 2014--2015
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{blueXIIlight}\rule{30cm}{8pt}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've removed some personal data here: I couldn't find the image needed to rebuild the screenshot, so have had to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\definecolor{blueXIIdark}{cmyk}{1,.8,.30,.05}
\definecolor{blueXIIlight}{cmyk}{.0,.30,1,.00}
\vspace{0cm}
\noindent\hspace{-2.6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logobalk}};
%    \draw (5.9,0) node (example-tabular) {
%\begin{tabular}{rr}
%\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Faculteit Geneeskunde en \\
%\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Gezondheidswetenschappen \\
%\end{tabular}
%};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\Huge\color{blueXIIdark}\noindent Title\\
\huge\color{blueXIIlight}\noindent Subtitle
\vfill
\large\color{black}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
& \textbf{\Large Author name}\vspace{0.8cm}\\
  Promotor: & Eerste bachelor in de geneeskunde \\
Prof. dr. Profdoc & Faculteit Geneeskunde en Gezondheidswetenschappen\\ & Universiteit Gent \\ & Stamnummer xxxxxxxx\vspace{2cm}\\
& Academiejaar 2014--2015
\end{tabularx}
\vspace{2cm}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{blueXIIlight}\rule{30cm}{8pt}}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: I've formatted your code by highlighting it and using the `{}` button/hitting `ctrl+k`. So is this question answered? A working example would be better, even if it is, as it will be more useful to others.