# Graphics against page border

Tags: graphics, indentation

Using

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kleurlabel}};
\draw (5.9,0) node (example-tabular) {
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Faculteit Geneeskunde en \\
\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Gezondheidswetenschappen \\
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

in combination with `\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}` will print the image against the margin, thus 2.5 cm from the actual page border. How can I have it printed against the border of the page?

Thanks.

M.

Working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,x11names]{report}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{blueXIIdark}{cmyk}{1,.8,.30,.05}
\definecolor{blueXIIlight}{cmyk}{.0,.30,1,.00}

\vspace{5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0, 0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{kleurlabel}};
\draw (5.9,0) node (example-tabular) {
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Faculteit Geneeskunde en \\
\LARGE\color{white}\bfseries Gezondheidswetenschappen \\
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{5cm}

\Huge\color{blueXIIdark} Hello world!

\vspace{7cm}

\large\color{black}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
& \textbf{\Large Micha\"el Henrotte}\vspace{0.8cm}\\
  Promotor: & Eerste bachelor in de geneeskunde \\
Prof. dr. V. Achternaam & UGent stamnummer 01404753\vspace{2cm}\\
& Academiejaar 2014--2015
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1.5cm}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{blueXIIlight}\rule{30cm}{8pt}}
\end{document}
```

The image used:
[image]

Comment: There is a pretty high chance that this will be covered in [Cover page lay-out](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235559) if somebody gives an answer. Right now, both are somehow duplicates.

Comment: Have a look at section 17.13.2 (referencing the current page node) in version 3.0.0 of the tikz/pgf manual.

Comment: related: [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169808)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just downloaded your image as OQUUD.jpg and used my approach from [Make picture horizontally fill out page and stay at top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207332/make-picture-horizontally-fill-out-page-and-stay-at-top).

If you wanted the image at the bottom of the page, you would change the one line to

`\atxy{0in}{\paperheight}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{OQUUD}}`

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\atxy{0in}{0in}{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{OQUUD}}}
\begin{document}
%% Titlepage
\vspace*{.2in}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`TikZ` introduces `current page` node and options `overlay` and `remember picture` to place `tikzpictures` on fixed positions on the current page.

As this node won't *use* any space on the page, some extra `\vspace` or changes in top margin must be added to start text below the banner.

```
\documentclass[11pt,x11names]{report}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{blueXIIdark}{cmyk}{1,.8,.30,.05}
\definecolor{blueXIIlight}{cmyk}{.0,.30,1,.00}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[inner sep=0, anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) (banner) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{OQUUD}};
\node[text=white, font=\LARGE\bfseries, align=right, above left= of banner.south east]  (example-tabular) {
Faculteit Geneeskunde en \\
Gezondheidswetenschappen
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{3cm}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]