# Want to add a small resized logo in the upper left side on every page?

Tags: graphics

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \hspace{\paperwidth}%
    \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{Number sampe}
     }}}%


\begin{document}
\includepdf{Plagiarism.pdf}


\title{Lab Report}



\maketitle



\end{document}
```

I want to know how it is possible to include a small resized logo into every page I create. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take my answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235587/graphics-against-page-border/235607#235607 and make three changes: 1) change `\paperwidth` in the optional argument of `\includegraphics` to something like `.2\paperwidth`; 2)  Change `\AddThispageHook` to `\AddEverypageHook`; and 3) change the `\includegraphics` filename to your own.

Comment: Thanks it worked you just saved me from losing a whole day to figure it out. :)

Comment: If you remove the `*` from `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` the `Number sampe` should be placed on every page, but in the background (behind the pages of the pdf). If you use `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` it will be placed in the foreground. you can use this also to add a picture using `\includegraphics` instead of the `\makebox`.